# My MVC3 website always opens in IE compatability view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing new web site using MVC3 and jQuery, but while I was running, website always opens in IE8 or IE9 compatability view.

What do I have to do to open in standard mode?

Is there anything I can do these check in developer tools provided in IE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your website is located under your IntraNet  then it will always display in Compatability view by default (This is a default setting for IE 8 and IE 9).  To change this:

Go to Tools | Compatability View Settings

Then uncheck the box that says "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View"

And Make sure "Display all websites in Compatibility View" is not checked.

Comment: this worked but if some people cannot see compatability view setting in tools menu, you can press ALT+T to open tools menu anf there you will find compatability view settings.

Answer (score 11):

Tell IE to use the latest rendering mode add a meta tag to your layout page
    `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">`

Comment: +1, This is a great tag to place at the top of any root page :)

Comment: can some elobarate what this piece will do browser?

Comment: I'd give you all my rep if I could. This answer saved my bacon.

Comment: @prakash this tag tells the browser to use the latest available rendering engine - "edge" means "the very latest". You can also specify specific versions if you like, but I don't recommend it.